# CakePHP long sql query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

My Project based on CakePHP framework works with MySQL DB.
And there sometimes is running a long sql query. And I can't load any page in my project during this query. But when I execute this SQL query in Adminer (light PhpMyAdmin), I can load any page  and any select from DB.
Can you help me to configure it?

Comment: share your model , the query you are running otherwise it's kind of impossible for anyone to help you and please specify what you really want.

Comment: My query is select with inner join.
Like this
select a.*  from table_b b inner join table_a a  on b.id = a.b_id where b.some_field = 'some text'

Comment: when that happens, use this SQL command `show processlist` and see what is the query and fix it

Comment: I know about `show processlist;`
But I want to execute other query to open some page. i.e. products page.

Comment: I want that my project was multithreaded like Adminer.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that the problematic query is:

```
select a.* from table_b b inner join table_a a on b.id = a.b_id where b.some_field = 'some text'
```

You need to make sure that there are indexes on the following fields:

```
b.id
a.b_id
b.some_field
```

Comment: You talk about optimization. And yes, I have added indexes on these fields.
I want to execute several queries in other processes.
What I want to see:
I open one page and system starting this long query.
I open next tab in my browser and open other page in my page and continue surfing.

Comment: You say you can't run any page, that to me sounds like a case where perhaps you have a long running query and the connections stack up waiting for table locks to be released.  Are you sure this is the query that is causing problems?  Are table_b and/or table_a queried for every page load?

Comment: Sorry for my english.
I just want to use my site when this query execute.
As i can do when i execute this query in adminer.
Do you understand me ?

Comment: table_b and/or table_a  are not queried on every page load.

Comment: As long as the query is not locking up tables that your application uses, the applicatoin should be able to run normally.  No amount of multi-threading is going to change the fact that queries being made against tables that are locked by some process are going to have to wait until that query is done.

Comment: Ok, I did some analysis
I started the process with this query.
And then I tried to open another page. 
Then I have executed `show processlist;` and I saw this long process still running and another one sleeping.

Comment: What database engine are you using? You could try switching to InnoDB as it supports row level locking, MyIsam only supports table locking.

Comment: In lieu of a correct answer to vote on @RichardAtHome, you're getting a helpful flag.